I am so confused about lighting electronic matches with altimeter
I have an RRC3 altimeter, it has the power to provide 3 A current with 9 V battery (only 1 second when deployment happens). I'm using a 9V standard Duracell battery, but the matches I want to light are specified to 5 A at a voltage of 8.4 V.
I don't know which component I can use, so I need help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your 9 V battery has too high internal resistance to supply 5 A at 8.4 V. From the datasheet, it has about 3 Ω, so with a short circuit you get about 3 A max (and no voltage). To have 5 A at 8.4 V, you would need a battery of (9-8.4)/5=120 mΩ or less to supply it.
Either get a different battery or parallel about 30 of them (Duracell MN1604).

Datasheet of Duracell MN1604 (https://files.batteryjunction.com/frontend/files/duracell/datasheet/DURACELL-9V-MN1604-Datasheet.pdf)

So, can I use two serially connected Li-Ion batteries (Power-Xtra PX18650-20B - 3.7V 2000 Mah) with 6A maximum output?

@Chito Should be fine. Average voltage (7.4 V) is a tad bit low, but you need to check the voltage specs on your e matches. I would suspect that they aren't too picky.

Thank you so much. It will solve my problem =D
